# How to use addImplicitMap method of Xstream?

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I  want to serialize the class using xstream with the help of addImplicitMap method available in it. Class will look like:

```
class MapTest{
private Map<String, String> mapList;

public MapTest() {

    mapList= new HashMap<String, String>();
}

public void setServicesHealth(String id, String name) {
    map.put(id, name);
}
```

I tried like:

```
class MapTestMain{
public static void main(String args[]){ 
MapTest services = new MapTest();
services.setServicesHealth("ID01", "Jack");
services.setServicesHealth("ID02", "Neil);

    XStream stream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
    stream.alias("MapTest", MapTest.class);
    stream.addImplicitMap(MapTest.class, "map", "id", String.class, "name");
    String xmlStr = stream.toXML(services);
    System.out.println(xmlStr);
  }
}
```

But I'm not getting the correct output. My expected output is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<MapTest>
 <id>Started</id>
 <name>Started</name>
</MapTest>
```

Kindly help me out...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLDR: `addImplicitMap` will not allow you to remove the `<mapList>` container element and the `entry` elements and rename the key/value elements all at once (example 1 and 2). For more control over naming of elements in maps, use `NamedMapConverter` (example 3). To be able to do everything at once, you will need a custom `Converter` implementation (example 4).

---

Long answer:

There doesn't appear to be a good explanation on SO of what `addImplicitMap` does, and it's also not very clear in their documentation, so I'm going to try to explain here.

`addImplicitMap` will remove the container element but, when used like this, it will not let you remove the `<entry>` element or rename the key/value elements. For example: **(1)**

```
stream.addImplicitMap(MapTest.class, "mapList", "s", Map.Entry.class, null);
```

Results in:

```
<MapTest>
  <s>
    <string>ID01</string>
    <string>Jack</string>
  </s>
  <s>
    <string>ID02</string>
    <string>Neil</string>
  </s>
</MapTest>
```

Alternatively, `addImplicitMap` lets you store *only the values* of a map when writing (omitting the container element and key elements). When reading XML it recreates the map keys using a specified field of the value objects, so *the map key must be stored in the map value object*.

For example, we can make the map's value a `Service` object with an ID attribute and make Xstream store just the values and recreate the map from them: **(2)**

```
private Map<String, Service> serviceMap; // modified in MapTest

static class Service {
  private String id, name;

  public Service(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}

MapTest services = new MapTest();
services.setService("ID01", new Service("ID01", "Jack"));
services.setService("ID02", new Service("ID02", "Neil"));

stream.addImplicitMap(MapTest.class, "serviceMap", "s", Service.class, "id");
```

Outputs:

```
<MapTest>
  <s>
    <id>ID01</id>
    <name>Jack</name>
  </s>
  <s>
    <id>ID02</id>
    <name>Neil</name>
  </s>
</MapTest>
```

Note that here each `<s>` element is actually the serialized `Service` object, not a `Map.Entry` object.

---

This still doesn't quite solve your problem (and we had to change what was in the map too), so we can instead try the `namedMapConverter`. If we go back to using a map of `<String, String>` as you had originally, we can use: **(3)**

```
stream.registerConverter(new NamedMapConverter(stream.getMapper(),
                null, "id", String.class, "name", String.class));
```

Which gives the output:

```
<MapTest>
  <serviceMap>
    <id>ID01</id>
    <name>Jack</name>
    <id>ID02</id>
    <name>Neil</name>
  </serviceMap>
</MapTest>
```

Still not quite right, and I don't believe you can make it better without implementing a custom `Converter` class (there's a good tutorial [here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/converter-tutorial.html)). So we add the line (instead of the `NamedMapConverter`):

```
stream.registerConverter(new MapTestConverter());
```

And use a custom Converter implementation: **(4)**

```
static class MapTestConverter implements Converter {        
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        return type.equals(MapTest.class);
    }

    public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer,
            MarshallingContext context) {
        MapTest mt = (MapTest) source;
        for (Entry<String, String> e : mt.serviceMap.entrySet()) {
            writer.startNode("id");
            writer.setValue(e.getKey());
            writer.endNode();
            writer.startNode("name");
            writer.setValue(e.getValue());
            writer.endNode();
        }
    }

    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        MapTest mt = new MapTest();
        String id = null;

        while (reader.hasMoreChildren()) {
            reader.moveDown();
            if ("id".equals(reader.getNodeName())) {
                if (id != null) { throw new RuntimeException("Malformed XML, ID was set twice: " + id); }
                id = (String) context.convertAnother(mt, String.class);
            } else if ("name".equals(reader.getNodeName())) {
                String name = (String) context.convertAnother(mt, String.class);
                if (id == null) { throw new RuntimeException("Malformed XML: Found name without ID: " + name); }
                mt.serviceMap.put(id, name);
                id = null;
            }
            reader.moveUp();
        }
        return mt;
    }
}
```

Finally we get the desired result:

```
<MapTest>
  <id>ID01</id>
  <name>Jack</name>
  <id>ID02</id>
  <name>Neil</name>
</MapTest>
```

(sorry I don't have enough rep to make the following into links)

Full code for `addImplicitMap` example: pastebin.com/MYiAde3m

Full code for `namedMapConverter` example: pastebin.com/kVChup5x

Full code for `Converter` example: pastebin.com/vUTwaHkk